# How read text file from internet in background service ? android

Tags: android

i run in app a service , this service with Broadcast Receiver called when  " changed in connectivity " . i put a toast in service and work good for all API but my app need read a text file from internet . i am testing 5 way but all code work for Android 2.* And not work for Android 4.* and with change connectivity force close App.

### Service Activity

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    URL u;
    try {
        u = new URL("http://epnu.ir/app/jsk.txt");
        InputStream in = u.openStream();
        String inputStreamString = new Scanner(in,"UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = inputStreamString;
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return START_STICKY;
```

### Log.txt

```
05-01 08:58:00.273: W/dalvikvm(747): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service ir.epnu.servi@4173e4e0 with Intent { cmp=ir.epnu/.servi }: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2721)
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1353)
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1133)
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:462)
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at ir.epnu.servi.onStartCommand(servi.java:81)
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2704)
05-01 08:58:00.283: E/AndroidRuntime(747):  ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It raise NetworkOnMainThreadException because service is started by default in UI thread. So I recommend to use IntentService Rather Service as super class.

Do Like this:

```
public MyService extends IntentService{

}
```

Instead

```
public MyService extends Service{

}
```

For Better Understanding Read the article [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Caution:** A **service runs in the main thread** of its hosting process—the service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process (unless you specify otherwise). This means that, if your service is going to do any CPU intensive work or blocking operations (such as MP3 playback or networking), `you should create a new thread within the service to do that work. By using a separate thread, you will reduce the risk of Application Not Responding (ANR) errors` and the application's main thread can remain dedicated to user interaction with your activities.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Create an `AsyncTask` and execute the network request in background